# Hiding the port when connecting to a website through dns

Tags: java, web, jboss, dns, web-hosting

I have a website hosted at an IP address in `Jboss` `EAP` 6 on port `8080`.
I bought a domain name and mapped it to that certain address.

When someone connects to the domain name, they are redirected to `mydomainame:8080/home`.

How can I make it work without showing the port to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this port is specified by client not server. In other words,server only listening on the specified port and waiting for connections from any client.

Why clients need to specify the port? Cause our server isn't listening on defaut port which always is 80 with HTTP protocol (443 with https).

Why we not specify the port when we access most websites? That is because the web site servers are listening on defaut port which doesn't need to be explicitly specified. And our browser will use the default port automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For `http`, the standard port is `80` (specified by [IANA port number assignment](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers)). If you don't want to display 8080 you'll need to configure your jboss server to listen on port 80. Alternatively, add a reverse proxy on port 80 and connect it to localhost:8080.